# Magento 2 - Admin - Product Listing Grid

Tags: magento2, product, admin, grid, thumbnail

Requirement is - we have to change image of thumbnail in product listing of admin in magento 2. But we are not able to find how rendering is occurring. There is no template used for same we believe.

Can anyone suggest, what is the way of doing that ?

We would be very thankful to you :)

Regards,
Nid